# Saber los 2 valores mas chicos de un array

Tags: javascript, array, math

necesito saber los 2 numeros mas chicos de una lista y sumarlos. Alguien sabe como podria hacer? Pense en un filter pero solo me sirve Math.min(). Como hago que funcione para 2 numeros?

```js
let arrDes = [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
function minSum(arreglo) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
        let newArr = []
        if (arreglo[i] < 3) {
            newArr.push[i[i]]
        }

    }

}

minSum(arrDes);
```

Comment: Tal vez no sea la manera más eficiente, pero la más rápida es simplemente ordenar el arreglo y tomar los dos primeros valores. Para ello basta con usar el método  `sort` que contienen todos los arreglos.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez, una disculpa, estaba escribiendo mi respuesta al mismo tiempo que hiciste tu comentario

Comment: @HeytalePazguato no hay nada que disculpar, tu respuesta es buena, totalmente válida y creo que es la solución que está buscando el usuario. Solo comentaba que la ordenación  no es la más eficiente ya que la ordenación de un arreglo tendrá complejidad (con los algoritmos más eficientes) de `O(n log n)` mientras recorrer el arreglo con un `for` solo será de `O(n)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Buen día,

Puedes hacer algo así:

```js
let arrDes = [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
function minSum(numbers) {  
  numbers = numbers.sort((a,b) => a - b);
  return numbers[0] + numbers[1];
};

console.log(minSum(arrDes));
```

Explicación:

Primero ordenas el arreglo de menor a mayor con `sort((a,b) => a - b)` y luego sumas los índices 0 y 1

Comment: Mil gracias!!!!

Comment: @user272992, si la respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas.